# Requests.get() not accepting multiple coordinate entries saved as a list

Tags: python, api, python-requests, response

I'm a newbie to working with APIs. For some background, the API in question takes the following arguments in order to retrieve the response object:

- API_ID- ID credentials to access the API endpoint.
- API_KEY- Key to access the API endpoint
- Location- List of decimal Lat/Long coordinates (max 5)
- Start- Unix timestamp for start of observation period
- End- Unix timestamp for end of observation period

What I’m trying to do is create a class object that contains all the necessary information for retrieving the data. This class object is written as such:

```
class API_call:
    def __init__(self, app_id, app_key, location, start, end):
        self.app_id = app_id
        self.app_key = app_key
        self.location = location
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
```

When I create the API_call object, I have the API ID (`api_id`) and API Key (`api_key`) stored as strings and functions to create a user-generated list of coordinates (`enter_locations()`) and the start/end times as unix timestamps (`start_datetime_to_unix()`/`end_datetime_to_unix()`).

```
API_call_object = API_call(‘api_id’,’api_key', 
                           enter_location(), 
                           start_datetime_to_unix(), 
                           end_datetime_to_unix()
                           )
```

There are normally no issues with this step, except if I enter something wrong during the prompts, but that is fixed quickly. Once the object is created, I try to pass the different pieces of information into `requests.get( )` and save it as a variable.

```
response_object = requests.get(f’{URL_OF_THE_API_ENDPOINT}?app_id={API_call_object.app_id}&app_key={API_call_object.app_key}&location={API_call_object.location}&start={API_call_object.start}&end={API_call_object.end}').json()
```

I have played around with the issue enough to know that if I pass everything but the `API_call_object.location` argument, the script works fine. The issue has something to do with how the `location` argument is being interpreted. When I enter only one coordinate, everything passes and I get the response object I requested. But, if I enter multiple coordinates and return them as a list of tuples (e.g. [(40.66,-87.32),(42.54,-85.78)]) and then pass into `requests.get( )`, I get this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Converting the output of `enter_locations()` to a string doesn’t help. Neither does trying to pass the output of a different function that simply returns a static list. I’m including the script for the `enter_location()` function in case it’s relevant to figuring out this issue. I recognize it may not be the best approach, but it worked for what I wanted to do.

```
def enter_location():
    location_list = []
    count = 1
    Lat1 = float(input("Enter your first LAT coordinate ")
                )
    Lon1 = float(input("Enter you first LON coordinate ")
                )
    Loc1 = (Lat1, Lon1)
    location_list.append(Loc1)
    add_more = input("Enter more coordinates? Y/N ")
    if add_more == 'Y':
        Lat2 = float(input("Enter your second LAT coordinate ")
                    )
        Lon2 = float(input("Enter you second LON coordinate ")
                    )
        Loc2 = (Lat2, Lon2)
        location_list.append(Loc2)
        add_more = input("Enter more coordinates? Y/N ")
        if add_more == 'Y':
            Lat3 = float(input("Enter your third LAT coordinate ")
                        )
            Lon3 = float(input("Enter you third LON coordinate ")
                        )
            Loc3 = (Lat3, Lon3)
            location_list.append(Loc3)
            add_more = input("Enter more coordinates? Y/N ")
            if add_more == 'Y':
                Lat4 = float(input("Enter your fourth LAT coordinate ")
                            )
                Lon4 = float(input("Enter you fourth LON coordinate ")
                            )
                Loc4 = (Lat4, Lon4)
                location_list.append(Loc4)
                add_more = input("Enter more coordinates? Y/N ")
                if add_more == 'Y':
                    Lat5 = float(input("Enter your third LAT coordinate ")
                                )
                    Lon5 = float(input("Enter you third LON coordinate ")
                                )
                    Loc5 = (Lat5, Lon5)
                    location_list.append(Loc5)
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
    return location_list
```

Comment: You do not **have** to have an `else` block... all these `else: pass` are totally unnecessary

Comment: Please, reduce the code to provide a [mcve]